# Go to ~ (tilde character) directory path

Tags: go

I'm trying to execute a command in golang, which goes to ~ path.
Like running `ls ~` in terminal.

Eventually i'd like to create commands in specific directory, which is located on ~/TestDirectory, for example, git pull, mkdir, etc..

Here's what i've tried :

1. `out, _ := exec.Command("ls", "~").Output()` -> Output is blank, so running `exec.Command("cd", "~")` doesn't go to ~ directory.
2. `out, _ := exec.Command("ls", "../..").Output()` -> Output is 2 directories above my current, but its not the way to do it since the current project might be anywhere
3. Also, i've tried setting the current directory of the command, the output was nil.

   ```
   cmd := exec.Command("cd")
   cmd.Dir = "~"
   cmd.Run()
   ```

Comment: `~` is interpreted by a shell, not by the operating system.  Execute the commands through a shell or expand `~` in your application code. If you can use $HOME instead of `~`, then https://godoc.org/os#ExpandEnv may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` is expanded by your shell (to your `$HOME`, at least on POSIX systems; read about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)). You could use [`os.Getenv("HOME")`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) to get its expansion

> Also, i've tried setting the current directory of the command, the output was nil.

Each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has its *own* [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). But `exec.Command` is running a *new* process, so in your case only that process (not your own one) is changing its working directory. You want to use [`os.Chdir`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Chdir) to change the working directory of your own process.